# unordered_set creation for finding pairs of integers in a vector

Tags: c++, unordered-set

For finding pairs in a vector, I am using `unordered_set`. I need help in why the creation is not working.

I am working on some code trying to find the pairs in a vector. I needed `unordered_set` for the logic.

Here is my code:

```
int sockMerchant(int n, vector<int> ar) {
    set<int> colors = new unordered_set<int>();

    int pairs;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        if(!colors.contains(ar[i])) {
            colors.insert(ar[i]);
        } else {
            pairs++; 
            colors.erase(ar[i]);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Error message:

```
Solution.cpp: In function 'int sockMerchant(int, std::vector<int>)':
Solution.cpp:10:23: error: conversion from 'std::unordered_set<int>*' to non-scalar type 'std::set<int>' requested
     set<int> colors = new unordered_set<int>();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:15:20: error: 'class std::set<int>' has no member named 'contains'
         if(!colors.contains(ar[i])) {
                    ^~~~~~~~
```

Exit Status

```
1
```

I except the `unordered_set` to be created and contains to be used.

Comment: You’re trying to initialise a variable of type `set<int>` with a value of type `unordered_set<int>*`. `set` ≠ `unordered_set` and one is a pointer and the other isn’t. Any particular reason you use `new`?

Comment: My idea is the constructor is called and contains can be used.

Comment: If I use initialisation of unordered_set without using new, I get the following: 

Used the code :
`unordered_set<int> colors ; `

Error Message:
_Solution.cpp: In function 'int sockMerchant(int, std::vector<int>)':
Solution.cpp:14:20: error: 'class std::set<int>' has no member named 'contains'
         if(!colors.contains(ar[i])) {
                    ^~~~~~~~
_

Comment: why not do `std::unordered_set<int> colors;`?

Comment: It looks like you used to write in Java. In C++ you don't always need `new` to construct object. Just `unordered_set<int> colors;` is enough in this case.

Comment: Error Message: _Solution.cpp: In function 'int sockMerchant(int, std::vector<int>)': Solution.cpp:14:20: error: 'class std::set<int>' has no member named 'contains' if(!colors.contains(ar[i])) { ^~~~~~~~ _

**I get the above error**

Comment: Thank you. I need to use a combination of find and count and do the logic. 

There is no contains in unordered_set.

Comment: @user3355645 [`std::unordered_set::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) is new in C++20. Are you compiling with a C++20 flag?

Comment: @sklott You are right, I was using a Java logic to solve a C++ problem.

Comment: @Biffen I am using Hackerrank.com to solve the problem.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

Do not know if the flag is on.

Comment: @user3355645 Don’t use `std::unordered_set::contains`, then.

Comment: Thank you @Biffen.
I solved it using sorting vector and then checking the elements in i and i+1 position

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues here (and the compiler is nice enough to be really informative about it)

1. You're trying to assign `std::unordered_set<int>*` into a `std::set<int>` variable. The types don't match, one is a pointer (returned from `new()`) and the other is a local stack variable. The actual classes don't match either `unordered_set != set`
2. `std::set` nor `std::unordered_set` does not have a member function named `contains` (at least not in the current C++ standard, will be available in C++20). You can just use the `find` member function from within `std::unordered_set` to see if an element is already in the set.

You can have a look on the definition of the class in here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

In another note, if there is no need to use `new`, don't use it. The function does not return the set that you created. 
If you insist of using `new`, you should use `delete` after you finish using the set, if you won't do that you will have memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you Enosh.
I solved it using sorting vector and then checking the elements in i and i+1 position.